# Does The Fourier Series of $\sin(px)$ uniformly converges when $p \notin \Bbb Z$

Tags: fourier-series, uniform-convergence

As a part of a question that I solving about Fourier Series, I had to decide if the Fourier Series in the domain $[-\pi,\pi]$of $\sin(px)$ is uniformly convergent.

Notice that $p>0$ and $p \notin \Bbb Z$.
So far I found that:

> $$\sin(px)\sim  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n2n}{\pi(p^2-n^2)}\sin(\pi p)\sin(\pi x)$$

I don't Understand how to determine if the Series is uniformly convergent to $\sin(px)$.
I thought about using Weierstrass M-test but I don't sure how in that case.

Thanks:)